# Catalog item resuse snippet how to show "Nothing found error"

Tags: 2013, display-template, cross-site-publishing

**TL;DR**

Is there a way to have some kind of event or way to know when a `Catalog item resuse webpart` doesn't return an item to the `control template`?

**Here are all the details of what I have tried and the places I have looked**

We have a cross-site publishing 2013 on-prem site. The catalog is setup and everything is working. However if a user goes to a catalog item page for an item that doesn't exist the page breaks. I would like to display a **The item you are looking for doesn't seem to be here. Please browse our catalog or try your search again.** kind of message.

The problem seems to be with the catalog item reuse snippet which handles display getting the item information to the page. It is [described in this blog](https://blog.mastykarz.nl/inconvenient-catalog-item-page-page-not-found-404-experience/) and a possible solution to extend the catalog item reuse webpart is provided. However we can't create new webparts. So I'm looking for a solution within the client-side site-owner type of solutions.

First I looked at the snippet on my page layout. I had set it up to use custom Control and Item templates. But other than that I don't see any attributes in there that would allow me to handle when no items are returned. I do find it odd that the `NumberOfItems` is hard coded at 1, what is that about?

```
<!--SPM:<a2e8ead9d:CatalogItemReuseWebPart
    DataProviderJSON="{QueryTemplate stuff in here}"
    RenderTemplateId="~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Control_Project1.js"
    ItemTemplateId="~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Item_Project1.js"
    runat="server"
    UseServerSideRenderFormat="False"
    ResultType=""
    NumberOfItems="1"
    UseSharedDataProvider="False"
    OverwriteResultPath="False"
    ResultsPerPage="1"
    SelectedPropertiesJson="[&#34;Title&#34;]"
    Title=""
    Description=""
    MissingAssembly="Cannot import this Web Part."
    ID="g_8579ad6a_9991_40db_a92d_6ca6cdc7364c"
    __WebPartId="{8579ad6a-9991-40db-a92d-6ca6cdc7364c}"
    >-->
```

The template js files are autogenerated from the associated html files that I can edit and upload.

I looked into my `Item_Project1.js` template. But I noticed that on pages without associated items the item template file is is never loaded. So I can't put anything in that file to deal with the issue.

However the `Control_Project1.js` template is loaded even on an empty page. I looked at other control templates in my site and found the following bits of code:

```
var $noResults = Srch.ContentBySearch.getControlTemplateEncodedNoResultsMessage(ctx.ClientControl);
...
<!--#_     
if (ctx.ClientControl.get_shouldShowNoResultMessage()){
_#-->
        <div class="_#= noResultsClassName =#_">_#= $noResults =#_</div>
<!--#_
}
_#-->
```

I also tried adding a test in the code like

```
if(typeof ctx.ListData.ResultTables[0].ResultRows === 'undefined'){
   console.log("No data for you!")
}
```

But neither of those pieces of code every run. Using the debugger I see that the code I enter is wrapped in a function like `function DisplayTemplate_2d1c504c7e6941ff993e412cd306d1ad(ctx)()` and that further down there is some code to register that function as a callback for something.

I've also used the debugger to track the calls and events and it seems that in `search.cbs.js` there is some code like this which calls displayControlMessage if there is no items and calls processResultReady otherwise.

```
processResultReady: function(b) {
    var c = this.$9_5(b);
    if (!this.shouldRenderControl() && this.$1_5) {
        this.processDataProviderErrors(this.get_dataProvider());
        if (!this.hasMessages()) {
            var d = new Srch.ControlMessage(null ,0,-1,"HiddenWithNoResultsWarningMessage",Srch.U.loadResource("cc_err_HiddenWithNoResultsWarningMessage"),"","",null ,true,false,true)
              , a = [];
            Srch.U.appendArray(a, d);
            this.processDataErrorMessages(a)
        }
        this.displayControlMessages();
        this.setControlElementVisibility(false)
    } else
        Srch.Result.prototype.processResultReady.call(this, c)
}
```

But this is really getting into the SP weeds and I'm out of my depth.